# Using Incanter and Clojure Soup together

Tags: clojure, jsoup, incanter, name-clash

I am learning Clojure - it's a lot of fun! I am trying to use Incanter and Clojure Soup in the same file:

```
(require '[jsoup.soup :as soup])
(use '(incanter core stats io charts datasets))
```

And I get the following error:

```
CompilerException java.lang.IllegalStateException: $ already refers to: #'jsoup.soup/$ in namespace: user, compiling
```

I think I understand why, but how can I solve this problem? Appreciate this website and all the gurus on it!

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only actually use one of the `$` functions then you can exclude the other one

```
(ns myproject.example
   (:require [jsoup.soup :as soup]
             [incanter [core :refer :all :exclude [$]]
                       [stats :refer :all] 
                       [io :refer :all] 
                       [charts :refer :all] 
                       [datasets :refer :all]]))
```

or you can take the approach of explicitly naming the vars you want to refer to in your namespace and explicitly calling the others by `namespace-alias/function`, which would look more like this:

```
(ns myproject.example
   (:require [jsoup.soup :as soup]
             [incanter [core :refer [$ ... and others here ...] 
                             :as incanter]
                       [stats :as stats] 
                       [io :as io] 
                       [charts :as charts] 
                       [datasets :as dataset]]))
```

The `use` method of using other namespaces is discouraged in modern clojure code and has been subsumed by the refer form, so I use that form in these examples. It's also strongly encouraged to put the refer forms in the namespace declaration.